# In Java in Unit test, using Mockito, how to mock call to XML DocumentBuilder so it doesn't return FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to unit test a function, which among other calls another private function which reads a XML file from disk.
In unit test I don't want to depend on a real file on disk, but instead I want to use XML saved in a String variable instead.

I tried mocking both `DocumentBuilder` and `DocumentBuilderFactory`, but with no success, since `DocumentBuilder` still wanted to read the file from the disk, thus in unit test giving `FileNotFoundException`.

Using PowerMockito is something I would like to avoid.

Below is a short code snippet with which I was able to reproduce the issue.

Class which is being tested:

```
public class XMLReader {

    private void readXml() throws IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
        try {
            docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse("path/to/xml");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {}
    }

    public boolean functionForTest() throws IOException {
        readXml();
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my test class:

```
public class AppTest {

    private static final String CLUSTER_CONF_XML = "<element></element>";

    private static Document buildXmlFromString(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset())));
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testFunctionForTest() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = Mockito.mock(DocumentBuilderFactory.class);
        DocumentBuilder xmlDocumentBuilder = Mockito.mock(DocumentBuilder.class);

        try {
            Mockito.when(documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder()).thenReturn(xmlDocumentBuilder);
            Document doc = buildXmlFromString(CLUSTER_CONF_XML);
            Mockito.when(xmlDocumentBuilder.parse(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(doc);
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        XMLReader xmlReader = new XMLReader();
        boolean result = xmlReader.functionForTest();
        assertEquals(result, true);

    }
}
```

When running the test I receive `FileNotFoundException`, while the expected behavior would mocking the XML with content of XML saved in String variable used in test when doing the mock and thus avoiding the exception and test case passing.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Read up on explicit dependency principle. Just because mockito allows you to foster poor design practices, does not mean that you should encourage its use.

Comment: This code is tightly coupled to implementation concerns (code smell) that make testing it in isolation difficult. Consider refactoring the code to follow a more SOLID design that would allow for Single responsibility principle and separation of concerns to begin with.

Comment: A clearer version of Nkosi's point: You should be using the `DocumentBuilder#parse` version that takes an `InputStream` or `Reader`, which you can then supply to the method as a mock; open the file and pass it to the method separately.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue there is pretty simple: Your instance of `XMLReader` is calling methods from the "real" dependency, not from the mocks you made. You forgot to "inject the mocks".

I will suggest a simple (though not clean) solution, but you should consider re-designing for testability:

1. Refactor your `XMLReader` so that it receives a dependency of `DocumentBuilder` as argument of a constructor.
2. Also, instead of instantiating new `DocumentBuilder` on your `readXml()` method, use references of the dependency you injected via constructor.
3. Finally, when you instantiate `XMLReader` on your test case, use the constructor that injects that dependency I mentioned (using the mocks you just made). Then, whenever a call is made from the `readXml()` method, it would be called from the mocks instead.

Example:

```
public class XMLReader {

    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    private void readXml() throws IOException {
        try {
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse("path/to/xml");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {}
    }

    public boolean functionForTest() throws IOException {
        readXml();
        return true;
    }

    public XMLReader(DocumentBuilder documentBuilder) {
        this.documentBuilder = documentBuilder;
    }
}
```